# Is it possible to pass a parameter as "/parameter_value" in the URL and acces it using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, url, parameter-passing

Is it possible to pass a parameter as "/parameter_value" in the URL and get it using Javascript?

For eg: http://example.com/parameter_value  or http://example.com/index.html/parameter_value

Instead of using '?' and '&' for passing parameters, can I pass parameter using "/parameter_value" and access it using javascript in index.html page. I need to get that parameter value after "/" in index.html page. Please get me some possible solutions.

Comment: Yes. You need to use URL rewriting on the server so you still end up on the right page though.

Comment: also all your relative links will break, you can only use absolute paths for css, images etc (unless you set BASE tag).

Answer (score 3):

It is possible do get it via JavaScript, but you'll also need to setup your webservice to accept url rewriting.

Once you do that, you can parse the url by accessing the `window.location` properties.

[Here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/a-deeper-look-at-mod_rewrite-for-apache/) is a nice `mod_rewrite` tutorial for Apache.